# Unable to find user django-user: no matching entries in passwd file

Tags: django, docker

I was following a tutorial on docker and django.
Not really hard but at one time, i get on this error and i don't understand where is the error on the dockerfile.

I understand the error given by docker but dont understand what is wrong in the Dockerfile.

Docker file :

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN python -m venv /py && \
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    /py/bin/pip install -r /requirements.txt && \
    adduser --disabled-password --no-create-home django-user

ENV PATH="/py/bin:$PATH"

USER django-user
```

And here is the error :

```
Creating django-deploy-gap_app_run ... done
Error response from daemon: unable to find user django-user: no matching entries in passwd file
```

Any help is welcome
Thank's !

Comment: Was that user created beforehand? `RUN adduser django-user`

Comment: @Nealium it's already the last row of RUN command

Comment: @SUTerliakov Oh. Ty. That's one long asf command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By removing the image and docker-compose again, the error disappear.

I suppose, i made something wrong the first time, and while i keep composing with the old image problem juste keep popping.